# Stretch Wallpaper Across Dual Monitor With Different Resolution

Tags: windows-7, resolution, desktop-customization

I am using Windows 7, and I have two monitors with two different resolutions (1920x1200, 1280x1024). I am trying to stretch my wallpaper across both monitors and I am wondering if it is possible to do so without using other software such as [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a picture that is the correct resolution for these two monitors (1920x2224), set the desktop display to 'tile.' This will not be perfect though, because obviously some of the pixels will be truncated on the smaller screen. If you mean to use a small picture and literally use the 'stretch' setting, no you will not be able to because the screens do not align (1920 would not stretch the same as 1280).

Comment: Confirmed. I have a smaller monitor as my main display, and using tile  fits the wallpaper to the small monitor, and causes tiles to occur on the larger monitors. This is undesireable, but true.